# How to Draw a Folded Sheet of Paper

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to draw the following picture:
[image]

But, I would like to label the sides as $8.5$ and $11$ so that they are a standard sheet of paper.  How would I do this in TikZ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

​Maybe this is what you're looking for.
You have to set the variable `\y` to the value that gives the best result.
`\y` has to vary between `\h` and `\l`.
If you want a smaller picture, divide all the coordinates by a scale factor.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\y{9.5}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\l{8.5}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\h{11}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\a{sqrt(\y*\y-\l*\l)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\b{\y-\a}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\x{\y*(\y-\a)/\l}

    \draw (\l-\x,0)--(0,0)--(0,\h)--(\l,\h)--(\l,\y);
    \draw[dotted] (\l,\y)--(\l,0)--(\l-\x,0);
    \draw (\l-\x,0)--(0,\b)--(\l,\y)--cycle;

    \node[below] at(\l/2,0){$\l$};
    \node[above] at(\l/2,\h){$\l$};
    \node[left] at(0,\h/2){$\h$};
    \node[right] at(\l,\h/2){$\h$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Thank you for your answer!